# How to track goals submit form from which reference code with support from GTM and GA

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics, custom-dimensions

pls help my case. I need to track goals submit form from which reference code with support from GTM and GA

my current solution:

- I create universal analytics tag with track type page view and custom dimension(ex firstColumn) get value from query key.
- I create custom html tag then push event and data layer with value I get from form.
- I create universal analytics tag with track type event and custom  dimension(I call secondColumn) get value from data layer value above.

when I create custom report with first dimension is firstColum, and  second dimension is secondColumn and metric is event hit but no result.  do I done anything wrong?
if you have any other solution to archive my expect. pls give a guide. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the custom dimensions are at the hit level and you are sending one with the first hit and one with second hit, you get no result because there are no event hits with both dimensions.

Comment: yes, you right. I change dimension scope to session and now I can see my report. thank for your point out